# rules for usernames in windows domain

Tags: active-directory, ntlm

I'm working on a app that uses Jespa to do transparent SSO.  I'm using the NtlmSecurityProvider.  In my code, when I get the username looks like this:  "DOMAINNAME\username"

e.g.

```
<% out.println(request.getRemoteUser()); %>
```

prints this:  MYDOMAIN\myusername

Here's my question:

Will it always look like that, with the domain name *and* the username? or is it just the way our user accounts in our domain are set up?  Like, if I switched to a different windows domain, could I potentially get just the username without the domain and the backslash?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably more a support question for the Jespa folks.  The output is reliant on the behavior of their API.

In general, though, best practice for Windows is to always use `DOMAIN\username` format or `username@domain` format.

If you're worried about the format changing then I would suggest you write a class / method / utility that knows how to parse the results of `getRemoteUser()` and returns the parts to your app as you deem necessary.  Then if it ever does change you only have to change on piece of code to fix your app.